# linear layout height too large

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I reduce the height of the selected linear layout?  The linearlayout layout_height (also tried height) is set at 0dp but it's still twice as large (in height) as the nested textview and edittext fields.  I'm guessing this is something more fundamental I'm misunderstanding.[image]